# HTML5 video player onclick play/pause not working

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

**I want to play/pause while click on the video** 
My code is here,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script type="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1");
            function playPause()
            {
            if (myVideo.paused)
              myVideo.play();
            else
              myVideo.pause();
            }
            //your code here
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <video id="video1" onClick="playPause();" width="320" height="240" >
          <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

where did I stuck? it shows error like

> ReferenceError: playPause is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several issues:

- `playPause`is defined only after the page is loaded, but you're trying to bind it before. You can remove the `$(document).ready()` to define the function **before** it's binding.
- `document.getElementById("video")` returns `undefined` (unless it is a typo in your post) as your `<video>` element has id `video1`

Here is a working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <script type="javascript">
        function playPause() {
            var myVideo = $("#video1"); // or document.getElementById("video1");
            if (myVideo.paused) {
                myVideo.play();
            } else {
                myVideo.pause();
            }

            // Your code here
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <video id="video1" onClick="playPause();" width="320" height="240" autoplay="on">
          <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function playPause() is here defined into an anonymous function.

```
function () {
            var myVideo = document.getElementById("video");
            function playPause()
            {
            if (myVideo.paused)
              myVideo.play();
            else
              myVideo.pause();
            }
            //your code here
        }
```

That means playPause()'s **range** is only this anonymous function. That means you can't call it from wherever you want.

You should define it before trying to call it. Like that :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script type="javascript">
        function playPause(myVideo)
            {
            if (myVideo.paused)
              myVideo.play();
            else
              myVideo.pause();
            }
            $(document).ready(function () {
            var myVideo = document.getElementById("video");
            playPause(video);
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <video id="video1" onClick="playPause(document.getElementById("video"));" width="320" height="240" autoplay="on">
          <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in the code. The main is the id of the video is different from the one you are using. Try this snippet.

```js
            var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1");
            function playPause()
            {
            if (myVideo.paused)
              myVideo.play();
            else
              myVideo.pause();
            }
            //your code here
```

```html
<video id="video1" onClick="playPause();" width="320" height="240" autoplay="on">
          <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
```